# Passing an immutable reference when a mutable reference exists

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker, mutability

I have a `for` loop that iterates over a slice of `Point` structs. The `Point`s will have some fields modified in the loop, so the function containing the loop requires a mutable reference to the slice.

The problem arises when I need to pass a (immutable) reference pointing to the slice to a function within the for loop that iterates over the mutable reference:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut grid = vec![];

    grid.push(Point { x: 10, y: 10 });
    grid.push(Point { x: -1, y: 7 });

    calculate_neighbors(&mut grid);
}

fn calculate_neighbors(grid: &mut [Point]) {
    for pt in grid.iter_mut() {
        pt.x = nonsense_calc(grid);
    }
}

#[allow(unused_variables)]
fn nonsense_calc(grid: &[Point]) -> i32 {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=405e1b6998dd61365ca487584206b6b7)

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*grid` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:30
   |
17 |     for pt in grid.iter_mut() {
   |               ---------------
   |               |
   |               mutable borrow occurs here
   |               mutable borrow used here, in later iteration of loop
18 |         pt.x = nonsense_calc(grid);
   |                              ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

The compiler complains that `grid` cannot be borrowed as immutable, because a mutable borrow already exists. This is correct, and I can see the problem it is trying to prevent, but how do I achieve what I need to do? Ideally, I do not have to create a copy of the `grid`, as this can be expensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution to avoid borrow the array for the iteration would be to use indexes:

```
fn calculate_neighbors(grid: &mut [Point]) {
    for i in 0..grid.len() {
        grid[i].x = nonsense_calc(grid);
    }
}
```